# Java: lambda expression concatenates several String arguments

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I need to get a lambda expression which takes several `String` arguments, concatenates them and converts result to upper case.

I tried to make it directly:

```
(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) -> (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h).toUpperCase();
```

but obtained an error:

> Compilation error Main.java:1: error: incompatible types: incompatible
>   parameter types in lambda expression

How to implement string concatenation using lambda expression in Java?

UPD: I'm solving a [problem](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/2369):

[image]

Comment: What context does this lambda appear in?

Comment: Did you assign that lambda expression to a functional interface having a method with 8 arguments?

Comment: Is looks very much like a Collectors job... I'm looking at you Collectors.joining()

Comment: Well, they request seven arguments and you have eight... Now, we don't know how the testing code works

Comment: I'm solving the problem. I added the the screenshot of a problem to startpost.

Comment: Thank you, @kumesana! Indeed, I used eight arguments insteed of seven....

Comment: To relate to what @kumesana pointed out  => ***The testing system has the interface and can test your solution.***

Answer (score 1):

Need to create a functional interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Concat {
    String concat(String a, String b, String c, String d, String e, String f, String g, String h);
}
```

and now use the following code to craee a lambda

```
Concat concat =  (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h) -> (a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h).toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in startpost is OK - I used eight arguments instead of seven and that was my error.